# unable to find what class="ng-binding" is pointing to

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am very new to protractor and JS and is stuggling with a problem.

In page http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/ protractor tutorial calculates the result element as `element(by.binding('latest')`.

But I couldn't understand that. In the code I see that element defined as below:

```
<h2 class="ng-binding">0</h2>
```

Can someone please advise a general approach in such cases.

Comment: The description of that is in the tutorial you are reading, just a couple lines below that code... "by.binding('latest') to find the element bound to the variable latest. This finds the span containing {{latest}}".  Also it would help to read up on angular data binding

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I saw that. Iam struggling to understand how I could have known to use 'latest'. What are the steps for a similar situation next time.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find an answer to this question with my partner's help. She is a genius.
So when I inspect element from browser, I see below code

```
<h2 class="ng-binding">0</h2>
```

To understand what variable above tag is binding to, I had to check the actual source code, not the browser rendered version displayed above.

```
<h2 {{latest}}</h2>
```

this explains, why I need to use `element(by.binding('latest')` in protractor

Answer (score 2):

When you open the url in any browser,(I am using chrome), instead of doing right click and inspect element, Goto the menu View > Developer > View Source Here when you see your object you will find variable {{latest}} This is what used to find the element in protractor Adding a screenshot of the same.

[image]